# Functions and procedures in QTP/VBA/VB6

Tags: function, procedure

What is the difference between function and procedure ?Aprart from returning value 
Because function can also be used as a procedure if you dont return any value then what is the difference...then what is the use of functions ?
Please specify a scenario where we can use functions and procedures ??

Answer (score 0):

Since your title specifies VBA and VB6, I'll reference the type of subroutines used by those languages. VBA and VB6 use "Function" for subroutines that return a value and "Sub" for those that do not. It's certainly possible to use a Function for all of your subroutines and just ignore the return value. Unlike C++ and many other languages, you're not required to return a value from a VB function. Because VB automatically initializes all variables to default values (zero for number types, False for Boolean, the empty string for String, etc), any functions that don't explicitly return a value will simply return their default value, which you can ignore. For example:

```
Function MyFunc() As Long
    ' Nothing here
End Function
```

This function will return the value zero.

So while you can use Function in place of Sub and just ignore the return values, it's not a good programming practice. Other users of your code will assume you chose Function instead of Sub because you intended to return something meaningful and will likely be surprised to discover that you're not returning anything at all!

There MAY also be a slight performance hit when using Function vs Sub, due to the extra parameter value that is passed on the calling stack (the return value).